# CodeIgniter: Select the same like parameter on JSON list

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter

I'm trying to use `tokeninput` from [jQuery Token input](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/), but the data is from the API. I already got the data from API and made a JSON list (see below).

When a user inputs in my token input, it will select from the JSON list, like `user/auto_unit?queryParam=q` for example. It already gets the user input correctly, but it still returns all data, even those that do not match the user input.

What I want is when the user searches for "Sosiologi", the only values that would show are those string which have "sosiologi" in them.

Is it possible to get only the same values and how can I do that? Thanks in advance!

**My JSON list:**

```
// 20170401095401
// http://exp.uin-suka.ac.id/aspirasi/user/auto_unit?queryParam=Filsafat%20Agama

[
  {
    "id": "UA000001",
    "name": "Filsafat Agama"
  },
  {
    "id": "UA000002",
    "name": "Perbandingan Agama"
  },
  {
    "id": "UA000003",
    "name": "Ilmu Al-Qur'an dan Tafsir"
  },
  {
    "id": "UA000004",
    "name": "Sosiologi Agama"
  },
  {
    "id": "UA000005",
    "name": "Matematika"
  },
  {
```

**My JSON code to get the list**

```
function auto_unit() {  
    $data['unit'] = $this->m_simpeg->getAllUnit();
    foreach ($data['unit'] as $key ){
        $row['id']= $key['UNIT_ID'];
        $row['name']= $key['UNIT_NAMA'];
        $row_set[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($row_set);
}
```

Model to get API **M_simpeg.php**:

```
public function getAllUnit(){
    return $this->s00_lib_api->post_api(
        1001, 1, null,
        URL_API_SIMPEG.'simpeg_mix/data_view'
    );
}
```

Comment: I dont understand what you mean. Please provide more details.

Comment: @CodeGodie i want select from json list like the parameter 'queryParam=q' maybe u can check my edited explained

Comment: How / where are you calling `auto_unit()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your server side code as it is not filtering the array.
 Codeigniter sample code

```
<?php
function filter(){
$queryParam=$this->input->get('queryParam');
$res=$array.filter($queryParam);
return $res;
}
?>
```